Error: R3F: AndroidProgressBar is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend?
I'm working on a React Native project, and I'm using Three.js for rendering 3D content. I encountered the following error:
 Error: R3F: AndroidProgressBar is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? See: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#using-3rd-party-objects-declaratively

This error occurs when I try to render a progress bar while the 3D content is loading. I've already tried the following steps, but the issue persists:

Verified that the three package is correctly installed and imported.
Checked that all necessary components are correctly extended.
Made sure that the component I'm trying to use is correctly registered and imported.

Environment:

React Native version: 0.72.6
Platform: Android/iOS

Other Libraries:
"@react-three/drei": "^9.97.5",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
"expo": "^49.0.0",
"expo-gl": "~13.0.1",
"r3f-native-orbitcontrols": "^1.0.9",
"react": "^18.0.0-rc.3",
"react-native": "0.72.6",

Code:
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber/native';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { heightPercentageToDP } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import Loader from '../../../../components/loader';
import Model from './model';

const Male_Army_Model = () => {
 return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <Canvas
       shadows
       gl={{ antialias: true }}
       style={{ marginBottom: heightPercentageToDP(3) }}
     >
       <ambientLight intensity={1} />
       <pointLight position={[10, 70, 70]} intensity={1.5} castShadow />
       <directionalLight
         position={[5, 5, 5]}
         intensity={1.5}
         castShadow
         shadow-mapSize-width={2048}
         shadow-mapSize-height={2048}
       />
       <directionalLight
         position={[-5, -5, -5]}
         intensity={1.5}
         castShadow
         shadow-mapSize-width={2048}
         shadow-mapSize-height={2048}
       />
       <directionalLight
         position={[2, -2, 1]}
         intensity={1.5}
         castShadow
         shadow-mapSize-width={2048}
         shadow-mapSize-height={2048}
       />
       <directionalLight
         position={[-2, 2, -1]}
         intensity={1.5}
         castShadow
         shadow-mapSize-width={2048}
         shadow-mapSize-height={2048}
       />

       <OrbitControls
         enableRotate
         enableZoom={false}
         rotateSpeed={1.0} // Consider reducing the rotate speed for smoother control
         enablePan={false}
         maxZoom={0.6}
         minZoom={0.6}
         maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 3.5}
         minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 3.5}
       />

       <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
         <Model />
       </Suspense>
     </Canvas>
   </View>
 );
};

export default Male_Army_Model;

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Could you show code from progress bar? Did you try extending it, according to what error says?

I haven't used AndroidProgressBar in my entire code. Could you please provide an example of how to extend it?

It turns out that the model configuration was not the same as the previous models we had successfully used. After identifying this discrepancy, I asked the model designer to create the model with the exact configuration by matching it to our earlier models. Upon closer inspection, the differences were primarily in the model textures.
Once these adjustments were made, and the configuration was aligned correctly with the specifications from our previous models, the model started working properly.
Key Takeaways:

Match Configurations Carefully: Always ensure that the model's
configuration, including textures and other details, matches exactly
with the previous models or the required specifications.
Attention to Detail: Even small changes in the model's
configuration, especially in textures, can cause significant issues in
performance.
Consistency is Crucial: Consistently using the same specifications across all models in your project is essential to avoid such problems.

Make sure to double-check these aspects before finalizing your model to prevent similar issues in your project.

If you take a look at the error, you have a link to the official documentation on how to use third-party objects.
You need to use extend function.
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Canvas, extend } from '@react-three/fiber/native';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei/native';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { heightPercentageToDP } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import Loader from '../../../../components/loader';
import Model from './model';
import { AndroidProgressBar } from 'your-3rd-party-library';

extend({ AndroidProgressBar });

const Male_Army_Model = () => {
  return (

    // ...

        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <Model />
          <androidProgressBar />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Male_Army_Model;


Hi Łukasz D. Mastalerz,
Thank you for your assistance. However, I am not using anything like AndroidProgressBar in the entire project.

@MuneebQureshi Any chance to make code sandbox?

Sorry, but we are unable to do that.

@MuneebQureshi I recreated your configuration and had the same error. The content of the error depended on different code configurations (especially Loader), sometimes it was a simple div, sometimes something different... Try asking on the discourse, there are often r3f developers there.
